# How do I smoothly update the toValue/end point of an animation in Core Animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

I'm trying to emulate the effect Apple has as a progress indicator when downloading an app in iOS 7, somewhat of a pie chart:

[image]

My code's coming along pretty well. I can give it a value to go to and it will update to that.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGFloat radius = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2;
    CGFloat inset  = 1;
    CAShapeLayer *ring = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    ring.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, inset, inset)cornerRadius:radius-inset].CGPath;

    ring.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    ring.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    ring.lineWidth = 2;

    self.innerPie = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    inset = radius/2; 
    self.innerPie.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, inset, inset)
                                               cornerRadius:radius-inset].CGPath;
    self.innerPie.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    self.innerPie.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.innerPie.lineWidth   = (radius-inset)*2;

    [self.layer addSublayer:ring];
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.innerPie];

    self.progress = 0.0;
    self.innerPie.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (animated) {
        self.innerPie.hidden = NO;
        self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;

        CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        pathAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        pathAnimation.duration = 0.5;
        pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.progress];
        pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress];

        [self.innerPie addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
    }
    else {
        [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
        [CATransaction begin];
        self.innerPie.hidden = NO;
        self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;
        [CATransaction commit];
    }

    self.progress = progress;
}
```

My issue lies in *updating the progress while in the middle of an animation*. For example, if I'm downloading a file and the progress jumps from 0.1 to 0.2 (10% to 20%), I want to animate that. Say I give it a 0.5 second animation. What if, 0.2 seconds into the 0.5 second animation it jumps to 0.4 (40%)?

With my current code, it jumps to where it should have ended (when it should have animated) in the first animation (20%) and then starts animating again toward 40%.

What I'd like is for it to almost update the `toValue` to 0.4. At least that's what I think I want. Conceptually I'd like it to continue the animation toward the new value without interrupting the previous value. Smoothness, to put it simply.

How would I accomplish this?

*I know there's libraries to do this. I want to do it myself for learning purposes.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace

```
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.progress];
```

with :

```
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.innerPie.presentationLayer strokeEnd]];
```

Initially, `[self.innerPie.presentationLayer strokeEnd]]`will be 1, so you will need to set the initial value to 0. Add these 2 lines to place where you create your 'innerPie' :

```
self.innerPie.strokeStart = 0;
self.innerPie.strokeEnd = 0;
```

I've tested and it works.

Comment: This works well. My only question now is whether or not it's possible to have the circle progress fill at a consistent speed. Right now if I fill it up regardless of how much it takes 0.5 seconds. This means small fills will move slowly, and big fills will move quickly. Is it possible to make it fill at a constant speed?

Comment: @DougSmith : yes it's straightforward. Notice that duration = distance / speed. Here 'distance' is the difference between fromValue and toValue. 'speed' is the value you define (Eg, 0.5 per 1 second). Then you can calculate 'duration'. Use it in pathAnimation.duration = [duration calculated above];

Comment: @DougSmith : would appreciate if you can mark my post as accepted answer if it works for you.